# Expanding Text area- on blur event the text area minimize to its original size

Tags: jquery, textarea, expand

I have to create a text area which expand according the text.
The problem that the text area minimize to its original size (i don't want this to happen).

This is the code for expanding:  (it's taken from a precvious question)

```
$('texterea').keyup(function(e){
    if($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))) { while($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))) { $(this).height($(this).height()+1); }; } else { while(!($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth")))) { $(this).height($(this).height()-1); };
```

the html:

```
<g:form action="reply" id="${conversationInstance.id}">
    <div class="convo-body">
        <textarea class="reply input-text-big" rows="1" name="message" placeholder="Send a reply"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-16">
        <button type="submit" class="pull-right button-blue" disabled>Send</button>
    </div>
</g:form>
```

Comment: wow. maybe format that a little. And be more clear about what it is you are asking. Include your html or a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that code hurt my brain, so here's an edit of it:

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
        bw = parseFloat($this.css('border-top-width')) + 
            parseFloat($this.css('border-bottom-width')),
        thisTargetH = this.scrollHeight,
        thisOrigH = $this.outerHeight() - bw,
        diff = thisTargetH-thisOrigH;
    if( diff > 0 ){
         $this.height('+='+diff); 
    }
});
```

See [**this demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o328detj/2/) for a working example

Comment: the textarea doesn't expand

Comment: @saritrotshild oops, fixed the anwser code and the linked demo fiddle. Works now.

Comment: @Ted- How can I remove the scroll?

Comment: @saritrotshild just set the overflow to hidden, like `textarea{
    overflow:hidden;
}`

Comment: @Ted- 10x for your help.... but for some reason it still minimized when I click outside the textarea:(

Comment: @saritrotshild it doesn't do that for me... what browser/version are you using?

Comment: @Ted- chrome- Version 41.0.2272.104. This actually was my question... how to prevent minimize.

Comment: Ahh--you're talking about the post back causing a page reload? The textarea is empty when you see it minimized again?

Comment: @Ted- No, it's not empty